# KeyError at /project/

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

i want to convert my data of json type but i received this error please where is it my error in my code , in my terminal i receive two problems in this ligne  "droplet_list.append(droplets[i])"     and in this page views " 'droplets' : get_droplets()"

data of type json :

```
 {
"projects": [
    {
        "id": 173,
        "name": "test",
        "identifier": "a",
        "description": "a",
        "status": 1,
        "is_public": true,
        "created_on": "2020-07-12T05:17:20Z",
        "updated_on": "2020-07-12T05:17:20Z"
    },
```

***views.py :***

```
class GetDroplets(TemplateView):
template_name = 'blog/home.html'

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = {
        'droplets' : get_droplets(),
    }
    return context
```

**service.py :**

```
 def get_droplets():

headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json',
'PRIVATE-TOKEN': '',
'Authorization': ''
}

url='http://172.16.0.111/api/v4/projects/'
url_redmine='http://172.16.0.112:3000/projects.json/'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
r = requests.get(url_r, headers = {'Authorization': 'Basic =='})

droplets = r.json()
print(droplets)
droplet_list = []


for i in range(len(droplets)):
    droplet_list.append(droplets[i])
return droplet_list
return JsonResponse({'droplets':droplets}, content_type='application/json')
```

```
**table.html**:
           
                  <tr>
                  
                    <th scope="col">Id</th>
                    <th scope="col">Project Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Identifiat Project</th>
                   
                   </tr>
              </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for droplet in  droplets %}
    
      <tr> 
                  <td>{{ droplet.id }} </td>
                  <td>{{ droplet.name}}</td>
                  <td>{{ droplet.identifier }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like droplets is not a list, it is a dict

try this

```
for i in droplets['projects']:
    droplet_list.append(i)
```

Comment: the loop for it's for display the data json in table !

Comment: @gmizaamel - you are iterating through dict, not list. Show the output of droplets

Comment: Ok and how i can fix it ?

Comment: I gave you the code. If it doesn't help, give the the output of droplets

Comment: this is the output for droplet  [{'id': 129, 'description': 'amel', 'name': 'test-git', 'name_with_namespace': 'proxym / test-git', 'path': 'test-git', 'path_with_namespace': 'proxymi/test-git', 'created_at': '2020-07-16T14:30:06.152Z', 'default_branch': None, 'tag_list': [], 'ssh_url_to_repo': 'git@git.hakase-labs.pw:proxymi/test-git.git', 'http_url_to_repo': 'http://git.hakase-labs.pw/proxymi/test-git.git', 'web_url': 'http://git.hakase-labs.pw/proxymi/test-git', 'readme_url': None, 'avatar_url': None, 'star_count': 0, 'forks_count': 0, 'last_activity_at':}

Comment: @gmizaamel - can you edit the question and give the right code format?

Comment: @gmizaamel - now I see the real json structure, try the updated code

Comment: if I can display two data in same arrays I did two for loop ?

Comment: @gmizaamel - you can concatenate two arrays, for example `for i in droplets['projects'] + droplets['projects_new']`

Comment: for i in range(len(droplets)) and droplets['projects']:
        droplet_list.append(droplets[i]) 
        droplet_list.append(i)
    return droplet_list i want to display two data in same table but it dosn't work

Comment: @gmizaamel - feel free to ask a new question. It is not connected with django itself, your problem is in data structure